# IBM Connections 5: What is the URL to "all community forums"?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I look for the URL which requests an "all community forums" view as a deep link for a given community UUID.

For ATOM, that is /forums/atom/topics?communityUuid=[communityUuid].

But for HTML, I cannot find an appropriate URL.

The URL should request and render all forums of a given community. This is a view which can be manually navigated to by displaying Forums of a Community and switching from the Topics tab to the Forums tab.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for 
/forums/atom/forums/my?communityUuid={communityUuid}

read more here 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Getting_the_My_Forums_feed_ic50&content=apicontent

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Following the documentation, this would return an Atom feed (and is helpfull in its own right!) -- but I looked for an URL requesting the IC5 GUI/WUI with that content. I cannot test this actually however.

Comment: Testing on Greenhouse returned Atom. Is /forums/html/my?communityUuid={...} a better way? It says "topics I am following" in the description.

Comment: there is no unified view on community forums in the web / html